# svelte kit server side data load async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I want to do the fetch operation on the server side and show it on the front side. but it does not open the page until the data is loaded. I want it to load the data after the page is opened. I did the feth process for seo and the visitor does not see where I did the fetch process.

fetch.js

```
export async function fetchData(page) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://fetch);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Hata oluştu:', error);
  }
}
```

+page.server.js

```
import { fetchData } from '$lib/fetch';

export async function load() {
    let sliderData;
    let jsonData = [];
    let filteredData = [];
    const jsonDataPromise = fetchData('images');
    const sliderDataPromise = fetchData('slider');
    await Promise.all([jsonDataPromise, sliderDataPromise]);
    filteredData = jsonData.filter(item => item.category === '');
    sliderData = sliderDataPromise.data;
    return {
        filteredData: filteredData,
        sliderData: sliderData,
    }
}
```

page.svelte

```
<script>
    import Slider from '$lib/Slider.svelte';
    import welcome from '$lib/images/svelte-welcome.webp';
    import welcome_fallback from '$lib/images/svelte-welcome.png';
    import Images from '$lib/imageView.svelte';
export let data;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Svelte demo app" />
</svelte:head>
<section>
    <h1>
        <span class="welcome">
            <picture>
                <source srcset={welcome} type="image/webp" />
                <img src={welcome_fallback} alt="Welcome" />
            </picture>
        </span>
    </h1>
{#if data}
<Slider data={data.sliderData} />
{:else}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{/if}
</section>
{#if data}
<div class="image-container">
    {#if data.filteredData}
        {#each data.filteredData as image, i}
            <Images {image} />
        {/each}
    {/if}
</div>
{:else}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [stream data](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises) (read this), this works by returning a promise as a *sub-property*. You *cannot* await the promise in the load function, otherwise the wait happens before the page is returned.

So if you want to filter the data, you have to chain that to keep it a promise. Something like:

```js
const dataPromise = fetchData(...).then(data => data.filter(...));

return {
  streamed: {
    data: dataPromise,
  }
};
```